# How to get all the accounts of EOS mainnet for research purpose?

Tags: mainnet, account-name, api, public-key

How many accounts are there on the blockchain? Are there APIs/sites to get a list of all the account names/publikeys of EOS mainet?

Answer (score 1):

Update:

EOS NY Will Pull a Snapshot for you on request and they've also open sourced their code:

https://medium.com/eos-new-york/snapshots-as-a-service-airdrops-for-all-2bd51548b1ac

https://www.eossnapshots.io/

---

### account names/publikeys:

You can use a snapshot generator.  https://github.com/EveripediaNetwork/airdrop  Or you can use one of their snapshots which [**is a CSV**](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/EveripediaNetwork/airdrop/master/eos_snapshot.csv) that lists every account and their associated EOS balance.

Example ( hash / account name / public key / eos balance ) :

```
"0x90fc1f495111329a1669716a149b7da88bdcb234","gygenesis111","EOS5KFXy8LiruGAQqY1pzwp5GqCaUkpMivSkpQfu3Rgg78QyFRHmA","2580.9968"
"0x639a47924af07a5a0ec52b4d521501ce23f1a8f4","hagenesis111","EOS5tRjHNDPMxQfmejsGzNyQHRBiLAYEU7YZLfyHjvygnmmAUfYpX","10000.0066"
"0xeba01432d662fb77c3102029f790abb12098e1e1","hegenesis111","EOS5C6LCQPAiRFZdx2kaywtEKAXJmDnGQwWoqkGJeyeRTJuJSVR2w","87129.6372"
```

---

### How many accounts:

https://eosmeta.io/statisticsaccount

---

### API:

https://github.com/EOSEssentials/EOSTracker-API

https://eostracker.io/

Comment: Thank you. The CSV file is awesome. However, it is from EOS genesis state. How can I generate the latest one? Their github doesn't provide instructions.

Comment: https://www.eossnapshots.io/