# How to scrape all accounts/public_keys in EOS mainnet?

Tags: accounts, account-name, blockchains, public-key

I am doing a research project at University. Since the accounts and public_keys for EOS change dynamically. Sites like this https://eostracker.io only display 20 accounts per page and it doesn't display public_keys along with account names. Is there a way to get the latest version of available account names/public_keys on EOS mainnet?

Comment: eostracker has an API which may help you, and there are some more resources [here](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/1485/how-to-get-all-the-accounts-of-eos-mainnet-for-research-purpose). However, as far as I know, there's no easy way to do this besides inspecting all blocks in the log. mongodb plugin may make it easier in 1.1 release

Answer (score 1):

Best solution I can think of is running a mainnet node with `--plugin eosio::mongo_db_plugin` to get all accounts in a mongo collection. However, by default, the public keys are not stored in the collection, so you'd have to use `$ cleos get account <account_name>` to find all the keys associated with the account.

This is quite time/resources consuming, so I'd also be interested to read about more efficient solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this service which does this periodically for you: https://www.eossnapshots.io/